# Python importing modules error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I have an issue with python on Ubuntu. It seems some modules that are part of the standard package cannot be imported. Example in python am trying to import the following lines:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
```

The code generates the below error:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
ImportError: No module named MIMEMultipart
```

All packages have been properly installed by default since I can access the files via shell but not directly when executing a file:
    python email.py

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? What is your PYTHONPATH? Is MIMEMultipart module in the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Peanut gallery, but if you are calling your program "email.py", rename it. Scripts that are named the same as a given module mess with the `import`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not specifying the modules and the afferent sub-modules correctly. You should actually do:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
```

I used the `help` function of python to check what the email module contains under "PACKAGE CONTENTS" and deduced for example that `MIMEmultipart` is a class of `mime`:

```
help("email")
help("email.mime.multipart")
```

Edit:

An easy way to find where exactly an object lies in a given module ONLY in Python2 (python3 does not seem to work with this) is:

```
getattr(__import__("<module_name>"), "<object_name>").__dict__["__name__"]
```

In your case it's something like:

```
getattr(__import__("email"), "MIMEMultipart").__dict__["__name__"]
getattr(__import__("email"), "MIMEText").__dict__["__name__"]
```